# how to open image gallery in a post/page?

Tags: plugins, images, gallery

I have created image gallery in a page using Add media. When i click on an image, it takes you to the attachment page but doesn't show the image clicked, instead it just shows the title of the image and nothing else.

How to show the image in a page?

Comment: please suggest me a wordpress gallery plugin,When i click on an image it should shows in a popup with image,title, content, next and prev button to scroll all the image in that gallery

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a gallery, in the gallery settings (right side of the Edit Gallery screen), you have the option

Link to:

- Link to attachment page
- Link to media file
- Nothing

Link to media file will open the image.
Be advised that without some form of Lightbox plugin, the image will NOT open in an overlay/lightbox, but instead as a new document.

There are quite a few lightbox plugins available, or you could use Jetpack´s Carousel.